# sub event to interact with more than one control

Tags: vb.net, events, arguments, controls, sender

I want to call this snippet passing a "controlname" like a argument, then the sub interacts with the desired control

How I can do that?

This is the snippet:

```
#Region " Move a control in real-time "
    ' Change Textbox1 to the desired control name
    Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles textbox1.MouseDown
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            textbox1.Capture = False
            Dim ControlMoveMSG As Message = Message.Create(textbox1.Handle, &HA1, New IntPtr(2), IntPtr.Zero)
            Me.DefWndProc(ControlMoveMSG)
        End If
    End Sub
#End Region
```

UPDATE:
The solution:

```
Private Sub MoveControl(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _
        TextBox1.MouseDown, _
        TextBox2.MouseDown, _
        PictureBox1.MouseDown

    Dim control As Control = CType(sender, Control)
    control.Capture = False
    Dim ControlMoveMSG As Message = Message.Create(control.Handle, &HA1, New IntPtr(2), IntPtr.Zero)
    Me.DefWndProc(ControlMoveMSG)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can just use `sender`.  The `sender` parameter is a reference to whichever control is raising the event.  So, if you add this same method as an event handler for multiple controls, `sender` will be which ever control raised the event that it's currently handling, for instance:

```
Private Sub MouseDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles TextBox1.MouseDown, TextBox2.MouseDown
    ' Note in the line above that this method handles the event 
    ' for TextBox1 and TextBox2
    Dim textBox As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    ' textBox will now be either TextBox1 or TextBox2, accordingly
    textBox.Capture = False
    ' ....
End Sub
```

The `CType` statement casts the base `Object` parameter to the specific `TextBox` class.  In this example, the method only handles events for `TextBox` objects, so that will work.  However, if you have it handle events from other types of controls, you'd need to cast to the more general `Control` type (i.e. `CType(sender, Control)`).